# How to tell FIX acceptor not to send messages if 43=Y

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixn

How to tell FIX acceptor not to send messages if 43=Y

or if that is not possible to be done from client side...

How to tell my initiator app to ignore incoming messages if 43=Y

QuickFixN version 1.5.0

Comment: Hi Frank. What is the reason you would not send messages with 43=Y? Those are for signaling possibly retransmitted messages.

Comment: I want to ignore old execution reports that keeps coming from server to my app whenever my app disconnected abnormally

Comment: I would not recommend to ignore resent messages, especially when they are FIX.ExecutionReport(35=8)... you very likely want to know about the order outcome contained in it. You likely did not received it the first time, as per your session drop/disconnection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you're saying that your app is the Initiator, and it is connecting to someone else's Acceptor, right?  (Please correct me if I'm mistaken.)

In that situation, you can't really tell the Acceptor how to behave.  It's outside of your control.

What you *can* do, is inside your `OnMessage(ExecutionReport)` function, just wrap your behavior in

```
if(msg.Header.IsSetField(43) && msg.GetString(43)=="Y") {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Grant for the response. However, I've figured out a way to do it. Everytime my app received logon ACK, then set the targetMsgSeqNum to the latest. Then I will not receive old messages anymore

Comment: Anyway, a bit OOT, can you pls tell me why CheckLatency=N or MaxLatency=600 didn't work? I still keep getting SendingTime accuracy problem. QuickFixN version 1.5.0

Comment: Hacking the targetMsgSeqNum does not sound like a good way to go.  Messing with sequence numbers is rarely the best idea, or even a good one.

Comment: Is your clock accurate?  Is it sync'd with a time server?  Are you doing a lot of work on the QF thread (e.g. do you have time-intensive logic in your OnMessage() or FromApp/Admin callbacks)?  Your QF callbacks should return quickly, else they will cause a processing backup in the engine.  If you need to do time-intensive processing, shunt it to a worker thread.

Comment: OK, I will follow ur advice then,

Comment: Last question, I'm wondering if there is any callback like `OnDisconnect()`. Sometimes, my app suddenly got kicked out (like logon timed out) and I didn't know what is the reason before I open the log file.

Comment: QF/n doesn't have `OnDisconnect()`.